# is AWS spot instance block duration give instance reliably without interruption?

Tags: amazon-web-services

want to use spot instance reliable(without termination because of spot market price) for some duration, have following question for the same:

- is spot-instance with block duration run without interruption for given duration, and can we rely on that to not terminate instance because of market price of that instance?
- is the pricing for --block-duration is same as other spot instance?

Answer (score 1):

> is spot-instance with block duration run without interruption for
>   given duration, and can we rely on that to not terminate instance
>   because of market price of that instance?

Yes. You can run your spot instances for a maximum allowed block duration period of 6 hours without any interruption or termination even if there is any hike in market price.

> is the pricing for --block-duration is same as other spot instance?

No. The pricing is different(greater) than the Spot Instances without defined duration. Refer this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/) for EC2 Spot Pricing.